# whats wrong with my namespace's (child element's) in my XSD file

Tags: xml, validation, namespaces

I get the follwing error in my visualbasic

> The element 'order' in namespace 'OrdersSchema' has invalid child
>   element 'deliveryAddress'. List of possible elements expected:
>   'deliveryAddress' in namespace 'OrdersSchema'.

dunno if i understand it correct but isn't deliveryaddress a child of order ? so why is it complaining that its not expecting it ? or am i wrong in my think path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:os="OrdersSchema"
            targetNamespace="OrdersSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
      <element name="orders">
      <complexType >
        <sequence>
          <element name="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <complexType>
        <sequence>
          <element name="deliveryAddress">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element name='line1' type='os:lineType'/>
                <element name='line2' type='os:lineType'/>
                <element name='line3' type='os:lineType'/>
                <element name='line4' type='os:lineType' minOccurs='0'/>
              </sequence>
              <attribute name="orderId" type="string" use="required" >
              </attribute>
            </complexType>
            <unique name="uniqueOrderIdPerOrder">
              <selector xpath="os:order"/>
              <field xpath="orderId"/>
            </unique>
          </element>
          <element name='items'>
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
              <element name="item">
                <complexType>

                <attribute name='productId' type='os:productIdType'/>
              <attribute name='quantity'>            
                <simpleType>
                  <restriction base='positiveInteger'>
                  </restriction>
                </simpleType>
              </attribute>
                  </complexType>
              </element>
            </sequence>
            </complexType>
          </element>
          <element name='note' minOccurs='0' type='string'/>
        </sequence>
             <attribute name="orderId" type="string" use="required" >
             </attribute>
             <attribute name="type" type="os:typeType" use="required"/>
           </complexType>
          </element>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      </element>
      <simpleType name='lineType'>
        <restriction base='string'>
          <minLength value='1'/>
        </restriction>
      </simpleType>
      <simpleType name='typeType'>
        <restriction base='string'>
          <enumeration value='standard'/>
          <enumeration value='express'/>
        </restriction>
      </simpleType>
      <simpleType name='productIdType'>
        <restriction base='string'>
          <pattern value='(?i)p[-\s](150|1[0-4][0-9]|[[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]'/>
          <pattern value='A...+[$XYZ]\b'/>
        </restriction>
      </simpleType>

    </schema>
```

This is the XML file ? This file cant be changed i need to construct my XSD to validate this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<os:orders xmlns:os="OrdersSchema">
<os:order orderId="ord0001" type="standard">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>5, Elmstreet</line1>
  <line2>90210 Beverly Hills</line2>
  <line3>California</line3>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="P 150.aabaac" quantity="5" />
</items>
<note>Deliver after 5 pm.</note>
</os:order>
<os:order orderId="ord0003" type="express">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>Voskenslaan 30</line1>
  <line2>BE9000 Gent</line2>
  <line3>Oost-Vlaanderen</line3>
  <line4>Belgium</line4>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="A3546sdfsdf6546sdf654Z" quantity="10" />
  <item productId="p 149.SLKDOZ" quantity="5" />
  <item productId="P 100.xcvZEr" quantity="15" />
</items>
</os:order>
<os:order orderId="ord0002" type="express">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>Voskenslaan 32</line1>
  <line2>BE9000 Gent</line2>
  <line3>Oost-Vlaanderen</line3>
  <line4>Belgium</line4>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="P-99.ruioze" quantity="15" />
  <item productId="A123qze46548X" quantity="50" />
  <item productId="P 1.sqmfze" quantity="1" />
  <item productId="AoknY" quantity="20" />
</items>
<note>This is <b>very urgent</b> !</note>
</os:order>
</os:orders>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things wrong with the XML and/or the XSD.  It's not clear from your question which you're free to change.  For starters, the specific error you provide in your question can be fixed by prefixing the `os:` namespace prefix ahead of the `deliveryAddress` element:

```
<os:deliveryAddress orderId="o1">
    ....
</os:deliveryAddress>
```

You'll soon then find that many other elements similarly have to be placed into the `OrdersSchema` namespace.  Prefix them with `os:` too.

The first regular expression pattern in the XSD may have to be fixed, or special options may have to be set for the XML processor to accept it.  Xerces reports:

> InvalidRegex: Pattern value
>   '(?i)p-\s.[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]|A...+[$XYZ]\b'
>   is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This
>   expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.

The XSD design itself is questionable where it defines the `items` element to be empty (where the XML has `item` children to the `items` element).  Perhaps it's the XSD rather than the XML that should be changed here.

Comment: i changed my question @kjhughes , i can only change the XSD

Comment: I added the Item child element